# setting default directory on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I recently tried to install php on my raspberry pi, and a web server. By doing so the default location of user pi is now var/www, but it used to be /home/pi. How can I change it back to the way it was?

Answer (score 0):

The most proper way is to use `Virtual Hosts` in the directory : `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

The default is pointing to `/var/www/`

I'm always creating a user for a project and then I point the  `Virtual Host` and I use `SuPHP` for the security.

To solve your problem, look at the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

**Edit :**

is it a problem related to apache and php or system/unix ?